# Xcode Compile Error: Lipo: can't open input file

Tags: ios, xcode

/fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/zicjin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Baozou-iOS-gsgjiwiqjwffeheenpeffrqpytqx/Build/Intermediates/Baozou-iOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/Baozou-iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Baozou-iOS (No such file or directory)

Use virtual machines to compiler does not complain, but switched to the real machine (iphone5s) runtime compilation error will be so
[image]

[the sourcecode on github](https://github.com/zicjin/Baozou-iOS)

Answer (score 16):

Set your `Build Active Architecture Only` to YES, then it will work

Comment: It depend a library which can't be compiled on arm64. I can make sure if reset several commits, remove arm64 is no problem.

Comment: also In my case I had to remove armv7s too, then it compiled, although it was no use for me if the app wouldnt support armv7s, so I switched to another library...

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I just tried it with 7.0.1 and that's what I get.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me. I'm using a static library in my project and the issue was that I put the aggregate with the universal script as a target instead of using the library itself.

This happens when the universal script tries to generate the universal library but the library itself is not compiled, this script needs the library to be created before running.

Comment: I couldn't understand much above but what I did was build the static library's target first and then run the universal script and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 7.2 I had to set Enable Bitcode to No in Build Settings > Build Options.

Comment: In my case 'Enable Bitcode' is already set to No but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while migrating my project from Xcode 5.0.2 to Xcode 6.1. These are the steps that I followed to get it working.

1. There was a warning generated - "Used recommended settings ... blah blah" - I allowed Xcode to change my project to whatever recommended settings there was.This did not stop the error though.
2. In TARGET -> BUILD SETTINGS -> BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURES ONLY . I turned the flag to YES.
3. set  TARGET -> BUILD SETTINGS -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags : $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)

After step 3 -I cleaned and then build my project and Whoa the error just vanished!!!!!

Comment: Couldn't understand the 3rd step, in my case it's $(inherited), -framework Flutter etc. since I'm using Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

In your project > Build Phases

Place your lipo run script after CocoaPods scripts, your lipo will run after cocoapods finishes building its frameworks

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jwRK.png)

Comment: I guess now you can remove Lipo script, I removed it and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me in Xcode 12.4, in Mac os CataLina This issue was occured by Not Enough Storage, I have deleted derived and some other data, then Build for Diawi link was successfully created.