# None of my emulators can open input file

Tags: xcode

Recently, trying to run any of my emulators gives me errors like this:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo:
>   can't open input file:
>   /Users/dg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedySend-dxsddbeapbyckeghnedhuzagpwqf/Build/Intermediates/SpeedySend.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeedySend.build/Objects-normal/i386/SpeedySend
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> (null): error: unable to open executable
>   '/Users/dg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedySend-dxsddbeapbyckeghnedhuzagpwqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeedySend.app/SpeedySend':
>   No such file or directory

If I connect physical devices, like my iPad 2 or my iPhone 5, I can build and run my app on them without errors.

Xcode was recently upgraded to 6.4 but I do not know if that is related.

I saw some similar problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967290/xcode-compile-error-lipo-cant-open-input-file) and I tried turning Build Active Architecture from Yes to No as per suggestions there.  The result was that one of the three previous blocks of error messages disappeared:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> (null): error: unable to open executable
>   '/Users/dg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedySend-dxsddbeapbyckeghnedhuzagpwqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeedySend.app/SpeedySend':
>   No such file or directory

I'm pretty lost.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Did you quit and clean caches? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073

Comment: Yes, quit Xcode, restarted it.  Deleted the derived data, did a clear before building.

Comment: "quit Xcode, restarted it. Deleted the derived data, did a clear before building" That isn't quite what I suggested; try actually following the directions the linked post gives you.

Comment: @Matt there are three answers in the linked post.  They each seem to take a different tack.  Which were you suggesting?

Comment: The link I gave you was not to a question but to an answer.

Comment: @Matt - ah, sorry.  Now I see it.

Answer (score 1):

*This error usually happen when your director is **moved** and you opened the project or you **upgrade** your xcode.*

Try create one new project and copy and paste the code lines(creating new files in Xcode) of the project with error for your new project until looks like as the last project.