# Xcode 10 fatal error: lipo: can't open input file

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, static-libraries, xcode10, lipo

I'm building a static library in objective-c, in Xcode 9 I could build without problem but I'm blocked in Xcode 10.
Initially I had these two problems that I resolved with the answers below

[Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)

[Xcode 10: unable to attach DB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error)

Now I have this lipo error, and I already tried the solution of adding arm64 to the valid architecture and build only valid architecture

[build settings pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8cWM.png)

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myNewLibrary-gvpwgkkoffdnkybybgkafnqwepcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/arm64/myNewLibrary/myNewLibrary (No such file or directory)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Anyone have idea how to resolve ? thanks

Comment: This is normally a symptom of workspace corruption. You can twiddle around with different settings in Xcode, or you might try deleting the contents of `project.xcworkspace` and reopen the project to let Xcode regenerate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967290/xcode-compile-error-lipo-cant-open-input-file

Comment: Matt thanks but I already tried what they wrote there, but doesn't work. Cinder, how I can delete that file ? I can't find it in finder, thanks

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: Hi @Nitish at the end I "resolved" rebuilding the library following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/2430-how-to-create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: @Alex : Isn't this for a static library ? I am creating a Cocoa touch framework - dynamic library.

Comment: @Nitish you have to start from a static library, and from it you create the framework. It is explained in the second part of the tutorial.